# How to delete a app from two iPads

Tags: ipad

I downloaded a app on my iPad and used my apple ID on my brothers  I pad too and downloaded the game but he wants to delete it. how do I delete it it don't have the x On the app?? HELP!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't delete the app after powering off the iPad, you would have to restore the device to clean to remove an app that doesn't get an X to delete.